# Why does my Valgrind doesn't show the error line but instead other paths in macOS Seirra

Tags: c, terminal, valgrind, macos-sierra

My .c file codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* i had made the coding wrong on purpose. */
int main(){
  int g = 10;
  int h;

  printf("I am %d age.\n");
  printf("I am %dtall.\n", h);

  return 0;
}
```

[ex4.c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLgqM.png)

I ran this code : `gcc -Wall -g -o ex4 ex4.c`

And in my terminal this is the output i got:

```
ex4.c:8:17: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
  printf("I am %d age.\n");
               ~^
ex4.c:5:7: warning: unused variable 'g' [-Wunused-variable]
  int g = 10;
      ^
ex4.c:9:28: warning: variable 'h' is uninitialized when used here
      [-Wuninitialized]
  printf("I am %dtall.\n", h);
                           ^
ex4.c:6:8: note: initialize the variable 'h' to silence this warning
  int h;
       ^
        = 0
3 warnings generated.
```

[My terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4tQ7.png)

And i proceed to try and valgrind to check for memory leak :

```
valgrind ./ex4
```

And this is the output on my terminal :

```
iPatrickMac:trying_valgrind patrick$ valgrind ./ex4
==10836== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10836== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10836== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10836== Command: ./ex4
==10836==
==10836== Syscall param msg->desc.port.name points to uninitialised byte(s)
==10836==    at 0x1003A834A: mach_msg_trap (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1003A7796: mach_msg (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1003A1485: task_set_special_port (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x10053D10E: _os_trace_create_debug_control_port (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x10053D458: _libtrace_init (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1000A69DF: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x100018A1A: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==10836==    by 0x100018C1D: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==10836==    by 0x1000144A9: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==10836==    by 0x100014440: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==10836==    by 0x100013523: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==10836==    by 0x1000135B8: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==10836==  Address 0x10488bdcc is on thread 1's stack
==10836==  in frame #2, created by task_set_special_port (???:)
==10836==
I am 76077616 age.
==10836== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==10836==    at 0x1002A64D7: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002CE422: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002A433D: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002A2247: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x100000F67: main (ex4.c:9)
==10836==
==10836== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==10836==    at 0x1002A8E87: __ultoa (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002CE422: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002A433D: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002A2247: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x100000F67: main (ex4.c:9)
==10836==
==10836== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==10836==    at 0x10009A142: _platform_memchr$VARIANT$Haswell (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.13.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==10836==    by 0x10029E4D1: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002A8898: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002CE422: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002A433D: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002A2247: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x100000F67: main (ex4.c:9)
==10836==
==10836== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==10836==    at 0x1003B047E: write$NOCANCEL (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002A3200: _swrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x10029BD26: __sflush (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x10029E584: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002A8952: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002CE422: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002A433D: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002A2247: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x100000F67: main (ex4.c:9)
==10836==  Address 0x100b57b85 is 5 bytes inside a block of size 4,096 alloc'd
==10836==    at 0x100098616: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.13.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==10836==    by 0x10029EFD8: __smakebuf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002B3B1D: __swsetup (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002CE1BE: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002A433D: vfprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1002A2247: printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x100000F53: main (ex4.c:8)
==10836==
I am 1tall.
==10836==
==10836== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10836==     in use at exit: 22,136 bytes in 160 blocks
==10836==   total heap usage: 176 allocs, 16 frees, 28,280 bytes allocated
==10836==
==10836== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10836==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10836==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10836==      possibly lost: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==10836==    still reachable: 200 bytes in 6 blocks
==10836==         suppressed: 21,864 bytes in 151 blocks
==10836== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==10836==
==10836== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10836== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==10836== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

I'm confused why my valgrind doesn't display the errorlines and having other path being display.

Is there something wrong with my compiling or is there something wrong with valgrind on macOS sierra? Help guys ):

What are all this :

```
==10836== Syscall param msg->desc.port.name points to uninitialised byte(s)
==10836==    at 0x1003A834A: mach_msg_trap (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1003A7796: mach_msg (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1003A1485: task_set_special_port (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x10053D10E: _os_trace_create_debug_control_port (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x10053D458: _libtrace_init (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x1000A69DF: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==10836==    by 0x100018A1A: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==10836==    by 0x100018C1D: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==10836==    by 0x1000144A9: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==10836==    by 0x100014440: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==10836==    by 0x100013523: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==10836==    by 0x1000135B8: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==10836==  Address 0x10488bdcc is on thread 1's stack
==10836==  in frame #2, created by task_set_special_port (???:)
```

example of a valgrind that shows error lines:

```
==5190== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==5190==    at 0x4078B2B: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195)
==5190==    by 0x407CE55: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1619)
==5190==    by 0x40831DE: printf (printf.c:35)
==5190==    by 0x4052112: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==5190== 
==5190== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5190==    at 0x4078B33: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195)
==5190==    by 0x407CE55: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1619)
==5190==    by 0x40831DE: printf (printf.c:35)
==5190==    by 0x4052112: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==5190== 
==5190== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5190==    at 0x407CC10: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1619)
==5190==    by 0x40831DE: printf (printf.c:35)
==5190==    by 0x4052112: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==5190== 
==5190== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5190==    at 0x407C742: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1619)
==5190==    by 0x40831DE: printf (printf.c:35)
==5190==    by 0x4052112: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
```

How can i allow my valgrind on my macOS sierra to display the error lines accordingly without the other weird paths being displayed which i have no idea what they are.

Answer (score 0):

**C11 standard, chapter §7.21.6.1**

> [..] If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined. [..]

So, It is good that you haven't ignored this warning because the resulting behavior of this call is **undefined**.

Comment: I’m not quite sure what you are trying to say here ):